# Change font size and style in officeR's body_add_table() function

Tags: r, officer

I am trying to change the font size in a table within the officer's `body_add_table()` function, with no success. How can I do this?

I am using the following code:

```
body_add_table(my_doc, value = tab02, style = "table_template", font.size = 10)
```

Comment: If you want to format a table, I'd recommand to use package flextable instead. `body_add_table` is a simple tool for those who don't want to spend time on formatting a table

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change font size and style in officeR body\_add\_table() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53212878/change-font-size-and-style-in-officer-body-add-table-function)

Comment: Please do not post the same question multiple times

Comment: @Bruno Gurarita Did you manage to get this work? I am having the same problem

Comment: I think I did... I have to check