# In officer package, how to add a simple border to body_add_table?

Tags: r, border, officer

I'm using the `officer` package to create a Word document with some tables in it. I want the tables to have simple lines separating cells, but I don't know how to do it. I add each table with `body_add_table()`, and I know there is a function called `fp_border()`, but nowhere on the documentation or the internet I could find how to relate both functions. I tried calling `fp_border()` right before and right after `read_docx()`, and right before `body_add_table()`, but nothing works. I've also read that [package “flextable” should be used instead](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53223526), but in this case, what is the point in having a `fp_border()` function?

Looks like I will have to go with `flextable`, but I want to be sure.

PS: I got a very strange error here: `The tag [table] is too similar to [table]. If you think this new tag should be allowed, discuss it on meta.`

Comment: `body_add_table()` is meant to add quick table to a Word document where all the styling is set by one of the table styles of the Word document, i.e. one option would be to create your own table style which could then be applied to the table. `fp_border` is used to define a border object and when using officer could be used to set the border for e.g. paragraphs but it is also used by `flextable` to set the border styles for a table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution goes along these lines:

```
library(officer)
library(flextable)

tab = data.frame(...)
set_flextable_defaults(split=F)
dx = read_docx()
dx = body_add_par(dx,'Some text',pos='after')
dx = body_add_par(dx,'',pos='after')
dx = body_add_par(dx,'Some more text',pos='after')
dx = body_add_par(dx,'',pos='after')
ft = flextable(tab)
ft = set_header_labels(ft,values=gsub('.',' ',names(tab),fixed=T))
ft = border_outer(ft,fp_border(width=0.5))
ft = border_inner_h(ft,fp_border(width=0.5))
ft = border_inner_v(ft,fp_border(width=0.5))
ft = set_table_properties(ft,'autofit',width=1) # whole page width, 1 = 100%
ft = fontsize(ft,size=10, part='all')
dx = body_add_flextable(dx,ft)
dx = body_add_break(dx,pos='after')
```