# how to modify the style in body_add_table

Tags: r

I am new to officer package.

if we use sth like  `body_add_table(value = tbl_test, style = "table_template",alignment = "c")`

Is it a way that we can modify the style that we want to use? For example, modify a little bit on `table_template`? Is it possible to modify the font size? as default style can not display my table nicely.

It seems like someone asked this 3 years before here: [Change font size and style in officeR body_add_table() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53212878/change-font-size-and-style-in-officer-body-add-table-function)

But not real answer to that question. Anyone can help on this?

Many thanks.

Comment: TBMK this is not possible via `body_add_table`. If you want to format your table than you could do so via `flextable` as suggested by the author of the `officer` package in his comment on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53223526/change-font-size-and-style-in-officers-body-add-table-function). However, another approach would be to create a custom template where you set the table style to your liking in Word. Afterwards you could use this custom template instead of the default one provided by officer.

Comment: @stefan May I ask how to modify `table_template`?